# How to exclude some div form body for replace

Tags: jquery, html, dom, replace

I want to replace some content with JQuery function replace(), like this...

```
...
var content = $("body");
content.html(content.html().replace(/([a-zA-Z])[']([a-zA-Z])/g,'$1&#8217;$2'));
...
```

However, I want to exclude some div, like "#foo" or "#bar".

I try...

```
var content = $("body") > *:not("#bar");
...
var content = $("body").find(":not(#bar)");
...
```

but it doesn't work.

The only solution that works with me is to list one by one each div where to apply the expected replacement. This solution seems poor! :)

Thanks a lot for your help!

Cheers,

Vincent

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var content = $("body:not('#bar')");
```

Or using `not()` method:

```
var content = $("body").not('#bar');
```

Comment: Thx for quick reply! Yours suggestions do not work. I use Chrome 8.0 and Firefox 3.6.13 with Ubuntu.